# Changing E and B fields for every other timestep

Tags: python, scipy, physics, particle-system

I am using this "[Lorentz-force-scipy-vector.py](http://expeyes.in/python.html)" code to model the trajectory of a charged particle( in 2D). My issue is that I need to implement a condition where the electric and magnetic fields switch signs.

I don't have a code that is doing anything close to what I need, so I will try to illustrate this with pseudocode and my image. The blue plot is x vs. y and the green is x vs. dy/dx.

Basically, I need Ex and Bz to switch signs after every other hump. This condition is met whenever dy/dx has a relative extrema. So if the sign flip condition could be related to dy/dx, I think that would be optimal.

```
Bx,By,Bz = 0, 0, 4
Ex,Ey,Ez .001,  -.01,  0.0000001
t = (some time, dt)

if hump_number%2==0:
      Bz= -1*Bz
      Ex = -1*Ex
      x,y = lorentz_force_solver(B,E,t0)
else:
      x,y = lorentz_force_solver(B,E,t0)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQCbL.png)

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: The script you linked is set up to handle constant E and B vectors. Apparently you want to simulate the effect of non-constant E and B vectors. The most obvious choice is to represent E and B as functions of (x) rather than as constants in solver().